# How to stream data from a teradata database in node?

Tags: node.js, teradata, nodejs-stream

I want to stream data from a taradata database to my node js server. 
I'm using npm's JDBC package for connecting with teradata database.

I want to know if there's something like db.query('select statement').stream() for streaming data from teradata database ?

Answer (score 1):

No. The npm JDBC package is a wrapper around the JDBC API. The JDBC API does not offer any facility for streaming data, and the Teradata JDBC Driver does not offer any facility for streaming data.

Comment: Is there any way to fetch 1 million records from the teradata database in an efficient manner ?

Comment: (FYI -- We offer a node.js driver https://github.com/Teradata/nodejs-driver )

When communicating with any of the Teradata drivers, the Teradata Database packs many result set records into messages, so it is efficient to simply fetch the rows from the result set.